# Cosmological Event Horizon formula

Tags: cosmology, event-horizon

I've found this formula for the event horizon:
$$
D_\text{eh} = c\int_1^\infty\frac{\text{d}a}{a^2H(a)}.
$$

How is this solved to a simpler form?

For example the Hubble horizon is:

$$
D_{hubble} = \frac{c}{H(z)}
$$

Comment: I upvoted this, but I think you need to contestualize just a little bit the question

Answer (score 1):

with („ Mukhanov Physical Foundation of Cosmology“)

$$d_e=a(t)\,\int_t^{t_\rm{max}}\frac{dt}{a(t)}$$

for de Sitter universe $~t_\rm{max}\mapsto \infty~$ and $~a(t)=\rm{exp}(H_\Lambda\,t)~$

thus $~d_e=\frac{c}{H_\Lambda}$

Comment: this seems what I am looking for, but what is the denominator? Looks like Hubble parameter...

Comment: so the hubble horizon and event horizon are the same .. ?

Comment: No this wrong I took it out  , look here https://sites.astro.caltech.edu/~george/ay21/readings/Mukhanov_PhysFoundCosm.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a method basing on "Introduction to Quantum Effects in Gravity (Draft) - Mukhanov, Winitzki". You consider a photon travelling in an FLRW Universe then
$$ 0 = \text{d}t \left( 1 - a^2(t) \dot{r}^2 \right) 
\\
\int_{t_0}^t \frac{\text{d}t}{a(t)} = r(t) - r(t_0) $$
and later you take the limit for $t\to +\infty$. For example in a De Sitter Universe $a(t)=a_0 e^{Ht}$ and
$$ -\frac{1}{a_0 H} \left( e^{-Ht} - e^{-Ht_0} \right) = r(t) - r(t_0) $$
by taking the limit
$$ \frac{1}{a_0 H} e^{-Ht_0} = r(t_0) $$

Comment: Is Ht0, H(t0) or H * t0?